# Is InstallShield 2010 really necessary to support Windows 7 (against using InstallShield 12)

Tags: windows, installation, installshield

I have received an e-mail from Flexera containing the following statement:

*"We understand that many of our customers still using InstallShield 12 maybe having difficulties sending installations to Windows 7 desktops, 64 Bit servers or R2 2008.*

*Therefore we would like to provide this opportunity for you to erase these potential / current problems and upgrade despite InstallShield 12 being End of Life’d some time ago."*

We have not had any problems ourselves. I am interested to hear if anyone else has had any issues or whether this is a scare to get us to upgrade unnecessarily.

I did examine in some detail the differences at the original end-of-life notice but could not see any issues that affected our installations.

Interestingly they call this an 'amnesty' - almost implying we are criminals for not upgrading (cf OED).

Comment: Good question... does IS12 allow you to download the 64 bit prerequisites and prereqs for the later .Net frameworks? Or maybe the MSIs produced by IS12 do not comply with Windows Installer 4.5+ standards?

Comment: Support for Windows Installer 4.5 and higher features were never added to IS12. Things that worked before will tend to keep working on later versions of Windows or Windows Installer. But for new functionality you will generally have to consider the upgrade.

I believe .NET 3.5 or its SP1 required new functionality in the prerequisite engine, so the supplied prerequisite wouldn't work before the version to which it was explicitly made available; other than that kind of thing (which isn't well documented), prerequisites tend to be downwards compatible as well. (Don't forget the prereq editor!)

Comment: I have created my own pre-requisites for .Net 4 (both Full and client). This works OK for both 32 and 64 bit (so far at least).

One of the problems with InstallShield and MSI (for someone who only creates installations once a year) is the lack of documentation on the gotcha's. For example one I came up with today was it running SQL script in deferred system context - which means that when it accesses a remote SQL server it is using the machine account! BTW Changing this to run in deferred context fixes the problem. This is only documented in the community.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get me wrong, there are several other improvements to consider since IS12, but especially if you are creating .msi installations, you can probably continue to use IS12. In fact, if you are creating patches, you should continue to use the same version of IS that the base used until you can hop a major upgrade. You'll hit the occasional bug or feature limitation, and in particular Windows PCA may misidentify installers due to aged manifests (See InstallShield 2010 SP1's release notes for that).

If you have time to evaluate whether the upgrade it worth your while, I'd suggest starting with the release notes (search for InstallShield 20xx Release Notes, with xx as 08, 09, and 10 so far).

Comment: We are just creating msi installations (and as simple as possible too!).

I have only just ventured into creating SQL installations (see above)

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, no.  But really it depends on the InstallShield features being used by your installer(s).  IS12 is a pretty good product and if you aren't hitting any roadblocks then go ahead and stay put.  If I was on a version prior to 12 I'd be upgrading for certain.

Comment: This is what I found - all the bugs in 10.5 went away in 12.

Comment: Code signing is not working reliably in InstallShield 12 using SHA256. Resorted to signing web setup.exe after creation. However this means you cannot sign the 'wrapped' msi. Not found anything else as yet.

PS This is fixed in latest InstallShield as I tested using eval version.

Comment: FWIW my comments were almost 7 years old talking about a product now almost 11 years old.   At this point I'd probably upgrade to the latest InstallShield or migrate to Windows Installer XML.

Answer (score 0):

Our Installshield 10.5 multiplatform installers are working fine on W2K8 R2 and Windows 7.